# nested rails gems and gem management

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Rails is collection of several gems, all who's source resides in the rails repository, aka active_record has its own gemspec but is at github.com/rails/rails/active_record. While I use this stuff all the time, I dont really know the details of creating my own gems using this strategy. I have a project for work where certain codebases will be reused from project to project, and think that I would like to build gems for each recurring toolset. While the gems will always be used in a namespace, eg `Company::LegacyRecord` I think it would be ideal to have LegacyRecord, in this case be its own gem. What would be the rationale for building a collection of gems with a toplevel namespace, like Company, in my example, or rails as the top level namespace, versus gems that are totally independent?

Answer (score 0):

you probably only need to do that for very large projects.  The benefit is that you can "split up the functionality" across gems and each one is more specialized.

Comment: separation of concern I understand. I'm just curious why for example, the active record home is at github.com/rails/rails/activerecord versus github.com/rails/activerecord and why that format was chosen